# Prevent users from being able to pipe output to another users terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

So currently on this server if two people are logged into the same server, you can do something like:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat /dev/urandom | write username
```

It will print a bunch of junk to their terminal. I do not have root or superuser access to the server. Is there something I can do, as a user, to prevent someone else from piping output to my terminal?

Comment: You could have found @demure's flawless answer by reading the man-page to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mesg n` is a per user setting to turn off `wall` `write` and `talk` receiving

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mesg